# Program to function changeover

Tags: python

I am trying to learn how to create functions.  How would I change this code into multiple functions?

```
purchase = input('Enter the amount of purchase: ')
statetaxes = purchase * 0.05
countytaxes = purchase * 0.025
totaltaxes = (statetaxes + countytaxes)
totalPurchase = (purchase + totaltaxes)

print('The amount of purchase is $'), format(purchase, ',.2f')
print('State tax: $'), format(statetaxes, ',.2f')
print('County tax: $'), format(countytaxes, ',.2f')
print('Total tax: $'), format(totaltaxes, ',.2f')
print('Total: $'), format(totalPurchase, ',.2f')
```

Would it be something like this:

```
def main():

    purchase = get_purchase
    statetaxes = get_state
    countytaxes = get_county
    totaltaxes = statetaxes + countytaxes
    totalPurchase = totaltaxes + purchase

    print('The amount of purchase is $', purchase)
    print('State tax: ', statetaxes)
    print('County tax: ', countytaxes)
    print('Total tax: ', totaltaxes)
    print('Total: $'. totalPurchase)

def get_purchase():
    purchase = float(input('Please enter the amount of purchase')
    return purchase

def get_state():
    state = purchase * 0.05
    return statetaxes

def get_county():
    countytaxes = purchase * 0.025
    return countytaxes

main()
```

Is this correct?  If not, where am I going wrong?

I am doing this without a python interpreter because I am using a tablet right now waiting for a flight.

EDIT:  What I am trying to do is separate the top program into multiple functions.  When I enter this code:

```
def get_purchase():
    return float(input('Please enter the amount of purchase '))

def get_state():
    return purchase * 0.05


def get_county():
    return purchase * 0.025

def main():

    purchase = get_purchase()
    statetaxes = get_state()
    countytaxes = get_county()
    totaltaxes = statetaxes + countytaxes
    totalPurchase = totaltaxes + purchase

    print('The amount of purchase is $', purchase)
    print('State tax: ', statetaxes)
    print('County tax: ', countytaxes)
    print('Total tax: ', totaltaxes)
    print('Total: $'. totalPurchase)

main()
```

I get this error:

```
Please enter the amount of purchase 5000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "salestax.py", line 49, in <module>
    main()
  File "salestax.py", line 38, in main
    statetaxes = get_state()
  File "salestax.py", line 27, in get_state
    return purchase * 0.05
NameError: name 'purchase' is not defined
```

I am getting on the plane now but will check back at the layover to see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Was I of any help to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer follows your edit where you have altered your code and are now getting a runtime exception.

Functions def `get_state()` and `get_county()` both reference a variable named `purchase` which is not in function's scope.

You should pass `purchase` into each of the functions like this:

```
def get_state(purchase):
    return purchase * 0.05

def get_county(purchase):
    return purchase * 0.025

def main():
    purchase = get_purchase()
    statetaxes = get_state(purchase)
    countytaxes = get_county(purchase)
```

There are other ways to do this, e.g. a class based approach, however as you stated that you are learning functions, this is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You need to *call* your functions, by adding opening/closing parenthesis:

```
purchase = get_purchase()
```

In `get_state()` you have `state` and `statetaxes` variables - you want to use just one of those.

Also, as [mhawke mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24319649/119527), you need to make `get_state` and `get_county` take a `purchase` parameter, and *pass* purchase from main to those functions when you call them.

Other than that, your functions appear to properly separate logical operations.

Answer (score 0):

Code review:

Move the main() code to the bottom.

```
def get_purchase(): 
    '''Use docstrings to describe the function'''
    # purchase = float(input('Please enter the amount of purchase')
    # return purchase # no need to assign and then return the assignment
    # just return what you'd otherwise assign:
    return float(input('Please enter the amount of purchase')) # was missing a )

def get_state():
    '''calculate and return state taxes'''
    # state = purchase * 0.05
    # return statetaxes # see a problem here? what is statetaxes?
    return purchase * 0.05 # there, it's fixed!

def get_county():
    # countytaxes = purchase * 0.025
    # return countytaxes
    return purchase * 0.025
```

So we've moved your main() to the bottom.

```
def main():

    purchase = get_purchase() # now we're calling these with the ()'s
    statetaxes = get_state()
    countytaxes = get_county()
    totaltaxes = statetaxes + countytaxes
    totalPurchase = totaltaxes + purchase

    print('The amount of purchase is $', purchase)
    print('State tax: ', statetaxes)
    print('County tax: ', countytaxes)
    print('Total tax: ', totaltaxes)
    print('Total: $'. totalPurchase)
```

Finally, at the bottom of your module, don't just call `main()`, use the common Python idiom:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It prevents the code from executing main() if you import the module. When you import a module, its `__name__` is no longer `'__main__'` Relevant: [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do/20158605#20158605)